# Data not inserted in MySQL database, but there's no error

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, connection, sql-insert

First of all, I am new to the use of php, XAMPP and SQL. I put a lot of time in trying to solve this problem on my own but nothing I did solved it.

I want to insert data from a input form on my website into my Database. When I fill out the form, the script runs without complaints but no data is inserted into my database. Also no errors shown in myphpadmin, simply 0 rows returned.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include_once 'database.php';

    $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last_name']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
    $pin = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pin']);

    //Errors
    //Check for NOT NULL
    if (empty($first_name) || empty($last_name) || empty($username) || empty($password))
         {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=empty");
        exit();
    } else {
        //check if input charakters are valid
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first_name) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $last_name)) 
            {
                header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=invalid");
                exit();
            } else {
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username'"; 
             $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
             $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

             if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=usertaken");
                exit();
               } else {
                //Hashing Password
                $hashedpassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                //insert user into database
                $sql = "INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name, username, password, pin) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$username', '$hashedpassword', '$pin');";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
                exit();
               }
            }
        }

} else {
    header("location: ../signup.php");
    exit();
}
```

the database is standard setup with root, localhost and no PW

```
<?php

$dbServername ="localhost";
$dbUsername ="root";
$dbPassword ="";
$dbName ="ntust";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

?>
```

As I am also not very familiar with SQL, I start to wonder if the problem lies in my tables?

```
CREATE TABLE user (
id Bigint(20) Primary Key auto_increment,
username varchar(255) NOT NULL unique,
pin varchar(6) NOT NULL,
password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
first_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
last_name varchar(255),
last_modified_date datetime NOT NULL,
created_date datetime NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: What happens with the current code, do you end up on `/signup.php?signup=success`? You should parameterize your query rather than escaping. When you hash the escaped value it is going to come out different.

Comment: You also need to insert `last_modified_date ` and `created_date` or add default  value for these fields

Comment: try to catch the error with the help of  `try catch`

Comment: Don't escape passwords. It's not only unnecessary since you're only storing the hash, but it also changes the password before you're hashing it which requires you to escape it every time you're going to verify it as well.

Comment: Check your servers error log.

Comment: @B.Desai Thank you so much! I totally forgot about that and thats why it didnt´t work out for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Database Connection**

```
$dbServername ="localhost";
$dbUsername ="root";
$dbPassword ="";
$dbName ="ntust";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

?>
```

**Database Format**

```
CREATE TABLE user (
id Bigint(20) Primary Key auto_increment,
username varchar(255) NOT NULL unique,
pin varchar(6) NOT NULL,
password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
first_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
last_name varchar(255),
last_modified_date datetime NOT NULL,
created_date datetime NOT NULL
);
```

**Updated Code**

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['first_name']) && !empty($_POST['last_name']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['pin'])) {


        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $_POST['first_name']) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $_POST['last_name'])) {
            # code...
             header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=empty");
             exit();
        }
        elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $_POST['first_name']) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $_POST['first_name'])) {
            # code.. check if input charakters are valid
             header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=invalid");
             exit();
        }


         include_once 'database.php';

         $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
         $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
         $username = $_POST['username'];
         $password = $_POST['password'];
         $pin =  $_POST['pin'];
         $last_modified_date = date("d-m-Y");
         $created_date = date("d-m-Y");

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username'"; 
                 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                 $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                 if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=usertaken");
                    exit();
                   } else {
                    //md5 Password
                    $md5password = md5($password);
                    //insert user into database
                   $sql = "INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name, username, password, pin,last_modified_date,created_date) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$username', '$md5password', '$pin','$last_modified_date','$created_date ');";
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
                    exit();
             }



    }
    else {

    $error = " Fill the all the details first";

    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($error)) {

        echo "$error";
    }

    }   
?>
```

Note: as i checked your database you, have an `last_modified_date datetime NOT NULL,` and `created_date datetime NOT NULL` So, Update it Based on this code, other every things is fine !!

Comment: Please stop using the `>banner` effect. I edited quite a few of your answers and most likely posted a comment inside it. This has been discussed [on meta]()https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355183/1415724). Also remove it and just use bold headings only.

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding. The OP is using the right method.

Comment: Turn the tide against teaching/propagating sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

Based to your experience I would say that the following the most appropriate solution.

Change your code to:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 

if (!$res) {
  printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

In this way you can check if there is an error on your query

> I would suggest to start looking for simple code debugging techniques and start searching for the appropriate documentation for `php` and `mysqli`

You can always check the `mysqli_error()` w3schools documentation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp)